# How do i replace input in my discord.py script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I've been trying to find a way to use input in my discord command but I failed a lot. If anyone can help me redo this code i'd be very gratefull :)

(bot = client)

```py
@bot.command(aliases=['execute'])
async def exe(ctx, *, code):
    str_obj = io.StringIO()
    try:
        with contextlib.redirect_stdout(str_obj):
            code = code.replace("input()", "random.randint(1,100)")
            exec(code)
        execute = str_obj.getvalue()
    except Exception as e:
        execute = f"{e.__class__.__name__}: {e}"
    
    if execute == "":
        execute = f"Unfortunatly, {bot.user.name} does not support input() function! If you have any idea on how to fix it please contact the creator of the script at *my discord*"
    
    embed = discord.Embed(color= color, title="execute.py", description = f"`{execute}`",timestamp=datetime.utcfromtimestamp(time.time()))
    embed.set_footer(text=f"{bot.user.name}")
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: That seems very dangerous. You could perform any computation with this including deleting the bot itself, wiping the database or hard drive. Remember: eval is evil

Comment: then how do i fix it?

Comment: You don't really, services like TIO usually spin up a container for each bit of code then destroy it afterwards to limit damage, you couldn't do this on "normal" hosting however. Even if you did you might still be vulnerable to DOS attacks simply by running code that takes long to complete, and you still have to be very careful securing your containers.